# 2004 Kia Sedona 160000 miles Timing Belt Replacement

Tags: timing-belt, kia, scheduled-maintenance, water-pump, timing

I have a 2004 Kia Sedona LX with 160000 miles on it.  I am going to be changing out the Timing Belt.  It will be the Car's second one.  What do you recommend I replace while I am inside?  Water Pump?  Idlers?   Oil Seal?   I didn't want to dig back in later for something I can do now.
Much Thanks
Reid Lantz

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, I would highly recommend visiting some forums dedicated to your make and model. Chances are there's a howto with common gotchas and recommendations specific to you. It seems like every model has its nuances!

Any idler pulleys or tensioners and the water pump are an excellent idea. They're not absolutely necessary as you've probably guessed, but the extra cost and effort are usually worth not having to do it again. That, and if one of them decides to give up the ghost it could cause the belt to hop off or rub until it burns up. In this case if it's an interference engine, you're looking at many thousands of dollars of repairs. If it's not, you're at least stranded.

The serpentine belt and tensioner may be a good idea if it's close to due since that will probably come off as well.

Except for ridiculously hard to access seals like a rear main seal, I wouldn't bother with any oil seals unless you're seeing a leak.